# Change from orthonormal basis to right-oriented orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm supposed to calculate a new HON (right-oriented orthonormal) basis from an ON (orthonormal) basis, where $e_1$ should point in the same direction as $v$ and $e_2$ should point in the same direction as $u \times v$.

$u$ has the coordinates $(-2,3,2)$
$v$ has the coordinates $(3,1,2)$

To get $e_1$, I have done this:

$$e_1=\frac{1}{\|v\|}(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3^2+1^2+2^2}}(3e_1+e_2+2e_3)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(3e_1+e_2+2e_3)$$

To get $e_2$ I used $$e_2=\frac{1}{\|v\times u\|}(v \times u)$$ and got the answer $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{65}}(-2e_1-5e_2+\frac{11}{2}e_3)$$
but that is wrong, and that makes the answer on $e_3$ wrong because I used this formula: $$e_3=e_2\times e_1$$
Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Does "ON" mean "orthonormal"? What does "HON" mean?

Comment: @ZevChonoles It means right orientated ON-base

Comment: That's something you should explain - people might not understand what you mean. Also, you can use `\sqrt{}` for square roots and `a_b` for subscripts. [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. You said you wanted $e_2$ in the same direction as $u\times v$. So aren't you off by a factor of $-1$? And, then, for a right-handed system you should have $e_3=e_1\times e_2$.

Comment: Thats the problem that I dont know if the way I want to get e2 and e3 is wrong but I know that e1 is correct